# How to find and edit the source of a string in a DX11 game's exe/files (debug build of the game available)

Tags: windows, debugging, strings, game-hacking, graphics

I want to find and edit the values for the motion blur effect in Naruto: Ultimate Ninja Storm 3 on PC (Windows, DX11) to be more in line with the PS3 version (and the other Storm games on PC as well). The PS3 version uses a very nice per-object motion blur while the PC version uses a crappy camera blur. The ultimate goal of this is to transfer this motion blur over to Storm 4 on PC which uses the same engine.

All of my findings are documented here:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1xxqOxLJwt04sgnIKqHHlfr8Gu6V_4toOFHv52P1FYEY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The "Jenkis" stuff is probably some kind of not removed developer log, not a file that the game creates on your drive. The blur may not be implemented in PC version, so it may be hard to edit

Comment: Thing is, there is a motion blur graphics option on the pc version that you can turn on or off, but it does literally nothing. I've taken screenshots and videos with the effect off and on to make sure I wasn't crazy and there is absolutely no difference with it on or off.

Comment: Bump for update at the start of the post